# how to login in with devise using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

This is my rspec file

```
    it "assigns all tool_cvt_remote_focus as @tool_cvt_remote_focus" do
      post "/users/sign_in", {:username => 'user', :password => "test"}
    end
```

rake routes

```
   users/sessions#new {:locale=>"jp"} new_user_session_en GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)
```

The error on console with POST method

```
 Failure/Error: post "/users/sign_in", {:user => 123}
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"/users/sign_in", :controller=>"users", :user=>"123"}
```

The error with GET method

```
 Failure/Error: get "/users/sign_in", {:username => 'user', :password => "test"}
```

Comment: What does your routes file look like?

Comment: Your rake:routes says it wants a GET request, but you are making a POST request with your test. Could that be your problem?

Comment: @ThomasO I tried the GET request, no luck too

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did some research and with Devise and Rspec and got your test working, albeit with some refactoring.

What I had to do was use the Devise helpers, to do that I had to add that capability into my spec_helper file:

```
require 'devise'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

Then I had to refactor your test to use these new Devise helper methods, otherwise Devise would throw me an error about trying to skip over the router.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Devise::SessionsController, :type => :controller do
 it "assigns all tool_cvt_remote_focus as @tool_cvt_remote_focus" do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    user = User.create(
      username: 'user',
      password: 'test'
    )
    sign_in :user, user
  end
end
```

Now, the way I created the user is not a best practice. From what I could tell online you are supposed to use FactoryGirl to to create the user because that is less fragile. However, as I have never used FactoryGirl and just wanted to give you the simplest solution possible, I decided not to include it.